# Selecting specific children on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide the divs on click using `.click()` event and `.hide()` method.

The thing is each one has a different `ID` that was 'chosen' by the user, so i can't just write the code for each case.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<body>
      <div id="box">
           <div id="div1"></div>
           <div id="div2"></div>
           <div id="div3"></div>
      </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(---selector for all divs 1,2,3----).click(function) {
          $(----specificDivIClicked----).hide();
     });
});
```

Basicaly, i'm trying to find a way to delete only the div i click on.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select all divs inside `box` div :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#box div').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#box div').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a valid JavaScript. Given that you have so much rep!

Comment: Why it's not valid??

Comment: `click(function){` should be `click(function(){`

Comment: That just a typo and it's fixed

Comment: See the above comment. `:)`

Comment: The idea is valid :) and you the man with so much rep downvote for typo instead of editing the post.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki The idea is to inform you, that high rep people shouldn't make mistakes. Your downvote is already removed. LoL. And converted to an upvote.

Comment: I'm a man and not a machine and we all trying to help each other here and not to beat each others, so be constructive in your comment/votes/edits. so instead of comment _This is not a valid JavaScript. Given that you have so much rep!_  + Downvote, you can just add the `)` to the post and it's done.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Sure I will do that from now. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Thy blanks have been filled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('[id^="div"]').click(function() {
          //------------------------^---- You are missing (
          $(this).hide();
     });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^="div"]').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```